# Convert existing bower foundation+scss website into wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, zurb-foundation, bower

I am currently trying to get used to using a combination between the foundation framework and scss, both auto-generated by the foundation cli which was recommended to me.

After building a small website, I am now trying to convert it into a WordPress theme which a program I currently know very little about yet, but I am completely clueless as to what files and how am I supposed to convert my scss from the foundation cli to WordPress.

Could anyone familiar with the Foundation cli files structure help me please?
Thank you all in advance for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to go with something like [FoundationPress](https://github.com/olefredrik/FoundationPress), a Foundation 6 WordPress theme. Foundation also has a nice list of WordPress [starter themes](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/resources.html). This may help you understand WordPress' general templating hierarchy a bit more so you can try to move forward and tackle what you've built.

The struggle of conversion is going to come down to falling in-line with WordPress template hierarchy and making all the pieces dynamic. There is not much that needs to be done with your Sass - you'll still be loading the same stylesheet and compiling as you were while building it out before the transition.

This is a good resource for [making a WordPress theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development). You basically need a style.css that defines your theme, header.php file to load persistent navigation and also define a spot to load script/styles (`wp_head()` within header.php), footer.php for the same reasons as header.php (`wp_footer()` within footer.php), functions.php to load styles with `wp_enqueue_style`, and index.php as your default page template.

This is a good base, but understanding the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) is also important. Comparing FoundationPress or even [TwentySeventeen](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyseventeen/) to the template hierarchy structure should help understand how it works. Hopefully this info helps point you in the right direction!

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response maxinacube. I believe to have understood the basic structure of wp now, but just cannot get my head arround as to how to import my scss files for it to be compiled into css there. I'll definitely check out the foudationpress you recommended, and once again thank you so much for your help.